# Can't buy anything through the app store on mac?

Tags: mac-appstore

I am trying to download Lion through the Mac App store, but its telling me that my payment method has been declined. I don't know what to do.

I've updated all my payment details and every time I check and re-enter my details again and again and each time I get the message "Your payment method was declined". I have no idea why this is. I regularly purchase items off the internet with the same payment method, and yet it just doesn't work with the app store!

On the internet apple store it seems to let me change my info without a hitch, is there something I'm doing wrong on the actual app store?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check with your "payment method" provider, e.g. credit card issuing company...

Comment: are you sure? It seems odd to only not work with the apple app store!

Comment: If your credit info is setup correctly, yes. I had a similar issue yesterday. I'm using a 3rd party provider for paying in the app store. my purchase was always declined. finally I had to resove it with my credit card issuing company...